# How to avoid Moiré effect when shooting with DLSR

Tags: dslr, shooting, moire

How can I avoid the Moiré effect when shooting with a DSLR camera?

Comment: What is your subject?

Comment: Usually people on street, and very often I can't use good testimonies because they are wearing clothes with striped or any other repetitive pattern.

Comment: Avoid patterns like brick as well. It all has to do with the size of your sensor. Small sensors can't handle that detail. If you can get hands on a big sensor like a 5D, that will be your best solution.

Comment: The stock Canon 5D2 and 5D3 both have terrible moire due to an incredibly naive algorithm for decimating their native resolutions down to 1920x1080.  Small sensors with good antialiasing filters, such as GH3, GH4, and GH5 crush larger-sensored Canons generally.

Comment: You could always apply a slight blur or some sort of creative effect to cover it up in post. Perhaps not ideal, but if it mean the difference between not being able to use any of your footage, and being able to use some of it, then maybe it's worth a try?